# Save Dialog Input

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have some buttons in my application, which open up a dialog when clicked on them.
In those dialogs a user can fill in his homework in an edittext.
Anyway i would like to save that user input, so that if I close the dialogs or the application I am able to recall that data and because I am new to eclipse and programming i don't know how to do it.

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected static final String TAG = null;
private Button bthomeWork;
private Button bthomeWork1;
private Button bthomeWork2;
private Button bthomeWork3;
private Button bthomeWork4;
private AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder;
private String strName="";




private void homeworkdialog(){
    dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText txtinput = new EditText(this);
    dialogbuilder.setTitle("Homework");
    dialogbuilder.setMessage("Was sind deine Hausaufgaben?");
    dialogbuilder.setView(txtinput);
    dialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ShowToast") @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strName+= txtinput;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Eingetragen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

    dialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ShowToast") @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kein Eintrag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    });

    dialogbuilder.show();

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);


    bthomeWork = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bthomeWork);
    bthomeWork1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bthomeWork1);
    bthomeWork2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bthomeWork2);
    bthomeWork3= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bthomeWork3);
    bthomeWork4= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bthomeWork4);
    bthomeWork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                homeworkdialog();
        }
        });
    bthomeWork1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            homeworkdialog();
        }
        });
```

Hope you can help me:)

Comment: in place of  `strName+= txtinput;` if you put  `strName+= txtinput.getText().toString();` then you can access your text with variable `strName`...

Comment: And if you want to set the text of the editbox to what you typed last time just do `txtinput.setText(strName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text and save the value of the editText into a String

```
String MyText = txtinput.getText().toString();
```

Then you can save the value either using sharedPreferences or into your Database depending on what you want to do

you can save the value in shared preferences like this

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
 sedt.putString("textvalue", txtInput.getText().toString());
 sedt.commit();
```

Then you can retrieve the saved text in another activity or anywhere in your project like this

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 String textValue = sp.getString("textvalue","");
```

for more information about using shared preferences check out this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

And also note that sharedpreferences are stored as simple xml values...so anyone with a rooted android phone can easily have accesss to the saved value...so if you want to keep the data safe you can check out ways of keeping data safe in android programming http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

Comment: How should the code look like if I use sharedPreferences? As I said I am new too it :)